# Job sites for applied/interdisciplinary Mathematics?

Tags: applied-mathematics, mathjobs, medicine

I was wondering whether there're job sites that post jobs in applied/interdisciplinary mathematics, more specially, say postdocs or higher positions in mathematics and medical imaging, mathematics and computer vision. I'm aware of mostly all the popular job sites, mathjobs, euro math jobs, fin math jobs etc etc, but most of the jobs there are are of 'pure' nature, with very few for applied/interdisciplinary. I find it a little strange, since it seems (I might be mistaken) that they've more funding in the interdisciplinary areas, which should mean they'd have more available jobs too, but I don't see any!

So, if you know any such website for the above (for Europe and the US), I'd appreciate if you could pass them onto me. Thanks! And sorry for having sounded so shameless about the funding comparison.

Comment: I doubt if there are any such sites. Your best bet is to look at physics/electrical/aerospace/mech engineering/CS scientific publications(and corresponding websites) such as IEEE, APS, SIAM, AIAA. All these have numerous job opportunities in applied math area.

Comment: This is not at all helpful for you, but I wanted to mention how pleased I was to see that in the mathjobs.org job listing page, next to all the alphabetical letters to narrow the list, there is also an "applied" option to narrow the list. I was equally disappointed to see that it just gives you a list of places you have sent an application to.

Comment: You can try www.jobs.ac.uk for all UK based jobs. It has a few extra filters than mathjobs.